# How to convert UPDATE operation into INSERT using triggers

Tags: postgresql, trigger

Given I have a table User with column status (active/inactive)

these users may be attached with some other entities, so I do not want them to get modified unless explicitly specified.
and for attaching to newer entities I only need the latest updated ones.

So when an UPDATE is performed, I want to make the existing row inactive,
and INSERT the updated values as a new row.

I am using PostgreSQL

Comment: [CREATE TRIGGER](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtrigger.html) .. INSTEAD OF UPDATE. Check if any field except `status` is modified.

Comment: @Akina Good idea; what about recursion?

Comment: Check out temporal tables

Comment: These triggers allows to specify the list of updated fields it is affected on. INSTEAD OF UPDATE OF *column_name1* [, *column_name2* ... ]

Comment: @Akina: `instead of triggers` can only be defined on VIEWs, not regular tables

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name What a problem to create a view?

Comment: I'd investigate query rewrite rules (`CREATE RULE`).

Comment: Of course it is possible to use BEFORE UPDATE trigger, where perform INSERT INTO using NEW.* values, and assign NEW.* back to OLD.* to prevent data update (except NEW.status which set to 'inactive').

Comment: But... when any complex logic exists I would think about by-query data alter prohibiting with moving it into stored procedure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not very complicated to do. If a BEFORE trigger returns a NULL value, this prevents the UPDATE from taking place.

So in the trigger function you can check the conditions if an UPDATE is allowed. If not, Run an `UPDATE` statement that marks the row as inactive and do an INSERT.

Something along the lines (**not** tested!):

```
create or replace function prevent_update() 
  returns trigger
as
$$
begin
   -- adjust this check to whatever you want to prevent
   -- but make sure to only enter this part if the status is not inactive.
   -- you might want to check pg_trigger_depth() as well to make sure you never create an endless loop
   if old is distinct from new and new.status <> 'inactive' then 

     -- The row was changed, but status column is the same, so we want to mark 
     -- the row as inactive 

     -- Because the new status is 'inactive' the trigger that is now fired for this UPDATE statement
     -- will not do anything because we only do this for status other than 'inactive'
     UPDATE the_table
       SET status = 'inactive'
     WHERE id = new.id; --<< the primary key column

     INSERT INTO the_table (id, some_column, status)
     VALUES (default, new.some_column, 'active');

     -- do NOT proceed with original UPDATE
     return null; 
   end if;

   -- all OK, proceed with the update
   return new;
end;
$$
language plpgsql;
```

And the trigger definition:

```
create trigger prevent_update_trigger
   before update on the_table
   for each row execute procedure prevent_update();
```

---

I would be **very** careful to deploy something like this. This kind of "magic" in the background might be the cause of a lot of confusion and trouble, so use with care!

Comment: instead `INSERT INTO the_table (id, some_column, status)
     VALUES (default, new.some_column, 'active');`
how can I just insert whatever is there, basically without having to specify column names

Comment: thanks a lot for the quick and descriptive answer

Answer (score 0):

Pasting here the code i developed using a_horse_with_no_name's answer , if that helps someone,
basically adding more dynamic queries, and table level lock to prevent race conditions.
Any suggestions on improvement are welcome.

```
create or replace function prevent_update_do_insert() 
returns trigger as 
$$ 
declare 
    pk_column text;
    other_columns text[];
begin 
    -- the purpose of this function is to prevent updates coming into tables which has a status column.
    -- treat any incoming update requests as, deactivate the existing then insert updated values as new row.
PERFORM pg_advisory_lock(quote_ident(TG_TABLE_NAME)); -- add lock prevent race conditions, any other concurrent invokations should wait.    
    -- make sure to only enter if existing status is active.
    -- we do not want to disturb inactive entries.
if old.status <> 'active' then 
    return null;
end if;

-- make sure to only enter this part if the status is not inactive.
if old is distinct from new 
    and new.status <> 'inactive' then 

    -- The row was changed, but status column is the same, so we want to mark the row as inactive 
    SELECT 
      a.attname into pk_column -- The primary key column
    FROM 
      pg_index i 
      JOIN pg_attribute a ON a.attrelid = i.indrelid 
      AND a.attnum = ANY(i.indkey) 
    WHERE 
      i.indrelid = TG_RELID 
      AND i.indisprimary;

    -- Because the new status is 'inactive' the trigger that is now fired for this UPDATE statement
    -- will not do anything because we only do this for status other than 'inactive'
    execute (
      'UPDATE ' || quote_ident(TG_TABLE_NAME)|| ' SET status = ''INACTIVE'' WHERE ' || quote_ident(pk_column)|| ' = ' || new.id
    );


    SELECT 
      array_agg(attname) INTO other_columns -- All other columns except primary key.
    FROM 
      pg_attribute 
    WHERE 
      attrelid = TG_RELID 
      AND attnum > 0 
      AND NOT attisdropped 
      AND attname not in (pk_column);

    -- Insert the UPDATE row as new row
    EXECUTE (
      ' INSERT INTO ' || quote_ident(TG_TABLE_NAME)|| '(' || array_to_string(other_columns, ',')|| ' ) VALUES ($1.' || array_to_string(other_columns, ',$1.') || ')'
    ) using new;

    -- do NOT proceed with original UPDATE
    return null;
end if;
-- all OK, proceed with the update
return new;
PERFORM pg_advisory_unlock(quote_ident(TG_TABLE_NAME)); -- unlock table level lock
end;
$$ 
language plpgsql;
```

And then add trigger

```
create  trigger prevent_update_trigger
   before update on the_table
   for each row execute procedure prevent_update_do_insert();
```